# What are the Specific heat ratios of fluorine, Isopropyl Alcohol and Uranium?

Tags: rocket-equation, heat, thermodynamics, hybrid-rocket

I needed to calculate thrust and velocities of a rocket engine and its exhaust and in order to do that, I needed the values of Specific heat ratio(k) of Fluorine and k of Uranium and Isopropyl Alcohol.

Comment: This seems to be a request for others to look information up for you. I think you can try that first yourself and then if you can't find what you are looking for update here and explain how far you've gotten. For isopropyl alcohol have you tried Wikipedia? For Fluorine and Uranium elements, you want F₂ gas and uranium metal? If so, those should be in Wikipedia as well.

Comment: And if things are coming out of the exhaust, it likely isn't solid uranium, or isopropyl alcohol as one molecule any more...

Comment: I tried looking for them over Wiki and Google but couldn't find it. It only shows only Heat  capacity at constant Pressure (Cp). And when I tried to calculate them I got -ve results for Cv and thus -ve for the ratio.  The Uranium-F₂ engine is a hybrid engine. F₂ passes through a solid uranium tube generating thrust. (Its not my idea but doing some calculations for a friend who thought of this engine)

Comment: The Isopropanol one is a simple engine. (Which I want to build for myself) It has Isopropanol as fuel and air as oxidiser.